Samsung Odyssey G7 32" Briefly disconnects when waking from sleep
I have a Samsung Odyssey G7 (the 32" model). I've had this annoying issue ever since I got the monitor.
Here is the problem:
Every time I wake the monitors up from sleep: My Samsung display briefly disconnects, and reconnects again.
Why is this an issue? Well the problem is that Windows thinks I've disconnected the monitor completely. So all the windows re-arrange themselves to fit on the remaining displays. I have 3 displays in total. All with different brands. The Samsung display is the only one acting up.
It's a pain in the rear to have to re-arrange everything again every time my monitors go to sleep. It's incredibly annoying.
Things I've tried to resolve it:

Re-install Windows completely.
Update the GPU drivers through GeForce Experience.
Removing the drivers completely from Safe Mode and performing a clean re-install.
Update the firmware on the monitor.
Look for settings on the monitor that might cause this (Found no such settings).
Google the problem, but can't find anything that matches my scenario.
I even tried ChatGPT to no avail.

I did find an article on the Samsung forums a couple years ago where someone had a similar issue to mine, where a service technician explained that the monitor is going into a state called "Deep Sleep". This means the CPU in the monitor shuts down the DisplayPort interface when it's in standby to conserve power, meaning Windows will see it as the monitor being physically disconnected. It was suggested that updating the firmware would bring it a new setting option to disable this behavior. My monitor is on the latest firmware, but I see no such setting. I can no longer find this forum post. Otherwise I would have linked it here.
My setup is as follows:

Form Factor: Desktop Computer
GPU: Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 TI
Display Name Samsung Odyssey G7 (32" model)
Display Model: LC32G75TQSRXEN
Display Firmware Version: M-TG700CCAA-1016.1
Connection: DisplayPort 1.2
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro (22H2)

